# Runge-Kutta time propagation with large stochastic error

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, runge-kutta-methods, error-propagation

I have to solve a differential equation of the type:
$$
\frac{d y}{dt} = f(t,y)
$$
$$
y(t=0) = y_0
$$
In general one would solve it with some high order Runge-Kutta method... if one could compute $f(t,y)$.

However evaluating $f(t,y)$ is extremely difficult in my case and can only be obtained with a significant stochastic error.
Let us call $f^*(t,y)$ the estimation of $f(t,y)$. Practically I cannot calculate $f(t,y)$, but only obtain a value with error $f^*(t,y)$.
Strictly speaking $f^*(t,y)$ is a stochastic variable with a normal distribution, with mean equal to $f(t,y)$ and known variance.

Before proceeding let me very clear.
I do not want to propagate the stochastic ODE: $\frac{d y}{dt} = f^*(t,y) $. I want to solve $\frac{d y}{dt} = f(t,y) $. The stochastic error is only a problem.

The most straightforward time propagation could be done by simply using Euler forward with the obtained value with error:
$$
y(t_n+h) = y(t) + h f^*(t,y(t_n))
$$

Apart from the low convergence order of Euler, using $f^*(t_n,y)$ is definitely sub-optimal.
The reason is that my time propagation gets the full error contained in $f^*(t,y)$.

But I can already think of a way to reduce it. At the step $n$ I have already calculated several $f^*(t_m,y)$ (with $m<n$) at previous times and I could use those calculated values to reduce my error: for instance I could make some assumption on the smoothness of $f(t,y)$ to obtain a better estimator for $f(t_n,y)$. One idea could be that I can assume some polynomial dependence on t of $f(t,y(t))$ and, from all the $f^*(t_m,y)$ values with $m\le n$, obtain the coefficients by inference. From that I can create an estimator for $f(t,y(t))$ with a reduced variance compared to $f^*(t_n,y)$.

Of course It would be even better if one could put all that together with a higher order Runge-Kutta method.

Does anyone know if a problem like that has been already addressed in literature? I could not find anything.

Comment: Does the error come purely from the evaluation of the function? That is, if you evaluate multiple times at the same point, you get always the same value with the same error? Or put another way, $f^*(t,y)$ is just that, not with a hidden probabilistic state $f^*(t,y,\omega)$, where $\omega$ is left out as usual in stochastic dynamics?

Comment: I evaluate the function f with Monte Carlo. Therefore if I were to evaluate it again I would get a different value.

Comment: You might have already discarded this idea, but is it too expensive or slow to average and then run the Euler scheme? You would compute a sufficiently large number of copies $f_1^*(t_i, y_i), \dotsc, f_n^*(t_i, y_i)$, average them to get an approximate $\bar{f}_i\approx f(t_i, y_i)$ and then take the step $y_{i+1}=y_i+h \bar{f}_i$ and repeat. If the known variance of $f^*$ is small, even $n>30$ variates should give you a decent approximation to the true $f$ at each point.

Comment: Surely that is the easiest way of doing it, but Euler forward has a very low convergence order, making everything way too expensive. The $f^*$ is actually a Monte Carlo estimation of $f$, so what you are suggesting is to compute $f^*$ with a lower variance. 
In the end I resorted to always computing $f^*$ with the same MC points. That means that $f^*$ is not a stochastic function anymore, but simply a function that differs a bit from $f$. Then I run high order Runge-Kutta on that.